# Cómo creo un método que retorne un diccionario que muestra la desviación estándar de columna en mi matriz de numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, numpy, método

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class Analisis():
def __init__(self, matriz = np.array([])):
    self.__matriz = matriz
    self.__filas = matriz.shape[0]
    self.__columnas = matriz.shape[1]
@property
def matriz(self):
    return self.__matriz
@property
def filas(self):
    return self.__filas
@property
def columnas(self):
    return self.__columnas
def as_data_frame (self):
    columns = [f'Columna{i}' for i in range(1, self.columnas+1)]
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(self.matriz, columns=columns)
    return dataset
def desviacion_estandar (self):
    deviacion1 = np.std(self.matriz.iloc[:,0])
    deviacion2 = np.std(self.matriz.iloc[:,1])
    deviacion3 = np.std(self.matriz.iloc[:,2])
    return {'DesEst_Columna1': deviacion1,
            'DesEst_Columna2': deviacion2,
            'DesEst_Columna3': deviacion3}
```

Definí el método_desviacion pero me da error. 
Traté definiendo otro método como este:

```
def desviacion_estandar (self, nc):
    deviacion1 = np.std(self.matriz.iloc[:,nc])
    return {'Columna' : self.matriz.columns.values[nc],
            'DesEst' : deviacion1}
```

Pero tampoco funcionó.

Este es mi array:

```
data = Analisis(np.array([[5,78,34],[6,2,8],[36,9,60]]))
```

Alguien me puede ayudar o decir qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el argumento `axis` con valor 0 de `numpy.std` para que te calcule la desviación estándar por columnas, luego simplemente genera un diccionario por compresión:

```
def desviacion_estandar (self):
    desviacion = np.std(self.__matriz, axis=0)
    dict_std = {f"DesEst_Columna{i}": std
        for i, std in enumerate(desviacion)
        }
    return dict_std
```

La salida para tu ejemplo sería:

```
{'DesEst_Columna0': 13.6106575888162,
 'DesEst_Columna1': 31.280984639234106,
 'DesEst_Columna2': 21.33512362279628}
```